# Presence/absence data

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, ecology

I'm working on a study where I am testing whether individual species that I observed or didn't observe (presence/absence of observing species A on each survey) during drought and non-drought (presence/absence of drought). I have about 150 surveys of presence/absence for species each during drought and non-drought. I'd like to statistically test whether individual species are more likely, less likely, or equally likely to be observed during drought or non-drought.

For a couple species, I did a contingency table/chi-squared analysis. Is this appropriate, or is there a better-suited method I could use? The convenient part about contingency tables is that I was easily able to implement my data as presence/absence columns (counts of surveys in which species A was observed versus surveys when it wasn't observed) and presence/absence rows (Drought Yes/No).

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: The chi-squared analysis could work, but be aware that if you conduct multiple tests then you may be more likely to get at least one false positive.

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the proportion of sightings differs between species (e.g. species b decreased during drought more than species a) or within species (species a sightings decreased during drought) or both? How many species are you testing for?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that

Comment: An issue with the chi-squared analysis is that the individual presences and absences for a species are most likely not independent.